# MY Expedia Air API results different than the resultsin expedia.com

Tags: php, html, xml

I have implemented Expedia Air Api in my php web site, I have sent air availability request to expedia and I got the result. But the price in the result is very different than expedia.com. I want to display the correct results. See my code below

```
<?php $post_string = 'cid=mycid&resType=air&intfc=ws&apiKey=wuxk5avnwqw9mygz8rjk8u5w&xml=<AirSessionRequest method="getAirAvailability"><AirAvailabilityQuery><originCityCode>COK</originCityCode><destinationCityCode>BLR</destinationCityCode><departureDateTime>06/03/2012 07:00 PM</departureDateTime><fareClass>B</fareClass><tripType>O</tripType><currencyCode>INR</currencyCode><Passengers><adultPassengers>1</adultPassengers></Passengers><xmlResultFormat>2</xmlResultFormat><searchType>2</searchType></AirAvailabilityQuery></AirSessionRequest>';




$path = "http://api.ean.com/ean-services/rs/air/200919/xmlinterface.jsp"; //Relative path to the file with $_POST parsing
$ch = curl_init($path); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_string); //Send the data to the file
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
$val = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch); //Close curl session
$fp = fopen('data.xml', 'w+');
fwrite($fp, $val);
fclose($fp);
```

IN MY RESULT PRICE IS DIFFERENT THAN THE EXPEDIA.COM. WHY THIS? If I HAVE MISTAKEN HOW I FIND OUT THE PRIE VALUE FROM

```
<AirAvailabilityResults size='16'>
   <AirAvailabilityReply>
    <supplierType>S</supplierType>
    <RateInfo>
      <nativeBaseFare>183.0</nativeBaseFare>
      <nativeTotalPrice>241.0</nativeTotalPrice>
      <nativeCurrencyCode>USD</nativeCurrencyCode>
      <displayBaseFare>9058.5</displayBaseFare>
      <displayTotalPrice>11929.5</displayTotalPrice>
      <displayCurrencyCode>INR</displayCurrencyCode>
    </RateInfo>
    <FlightSegment>
      <segmentOutgoing>true</segmentOutgoing>
      <segmentKey>AI519</segmentKey>
      <fareClass> J</fareClass>
    </FlightSegment>
    <tripType>O</tripType>
    <ticketType>E</ticketType>
  </AirAvailabilityReply>
  <AirAvailabilityReply>
    <supplierType>S</supplierType>
    <RateInfo>
      <nativeBaseFare>183.0</nativeBaseFare>
      <nativeTotalPrice>241.0</nativeTotalPrice>
      <nativeCurrencyCode>USD</nativeCurrencyCode>
      <displayBaseFare>9058.5</displayBaseFare>
      <displayTotalPrice>11929.5</displayTotalPrice>
      <displayCurrencyCode>INR</displayCurrencyCode>
    </RateInfo>
    <FlightSegment>
      <segmentOutgoing>true</segmentOutgoing>
      <segmentKey>AI509</segmentKey>
      <fareClass> J</fareClass>
    </FlightSegment>
    <tripType>O</tripType>
    <ticketType>E</ticketType>
  </AirAvailabilityReply>
  <AirAvailabilityReply>
    <supplierType>S</supplierType>
    <RateInfo>
      <nativeBaseFare>209.00002</nativeBaseFare>
      <nativeTotalPrice>274.2</nativeTotalPrice>
      <nativeCurrencyCode>USD</nativeCurrencyCode>
      <displayBaseFare>10345.5</displayBaseFare>
      <displayTotalPrice>13572.9</displayTotalPrice>
      <displayCurrencyCode>INR</displayCurrencyCode>
    </RateInfo>
    <FlightSegment>
      <segmentOutgoing>true</segmentOutgoing>
      <segmentKey>9W2306</segmentKey>
      <fareClass> I</fareClass>
    </FlightSegment>
    <tripType>O</tripType>
    <ticketType>E</ticketType>
  </AirAvailabilityReply>
  <AirAvailabilityReply>
    <supplierType>S</supplierType>
    <RateInfo>
      <nativeBaseFare>252.0</nativeBaseFare>
      <nativeTotalPrice>364.4</nativeTotalPrice>
      <nativeCurrencyCode>USD</nativeCurrencyCode>
      <displayBaseFare>12474.0</displayBaseFare>
      <displayTotalPrice>18037.8</displayTotalPrice>
      <displayCurrencyCode>INR</displayCurrencyCode>
    </RateInfo>
    <FlightSegment>
      <segmentOutgoing>true</segmentOutgoing>
      <segmentKey>9W2730</segmentKey>
      <fareClass> W</fareClass>
    </FlightSegment>
    <FlightSegment>
      <segmentOutgoing>true</segmentOutgoing>
      <segmentKey>9W2307</segmentKey>
      <fareClass> I</fareClass>
    </FlightSegment>
    <tripType>O</tripType>
    <ticketType>E</ticketType>
  </AirAvailabilityReply>
  <AirAvailabilityReply>
    <supplierType>S</supplierType>
    <RateInfo>
      <nativeBaseFare>262.0</nativeBaseFare>
      <nativeTotalPrice>383.0</nativeTotalPrice>
      <nativeCurrencyCode>USD</nativeCurrencyCode>
      <displayBaseFare>12969.0</displayBaseFare>
      <displayTotalPrice>18958.5</displayTotalPrice>
      <displayCurrencyCode>INR</displayCurrencyCode>
    </RateInfo>
    <FlightSegment>
      <segmentOutgoing>true</segmentOutgoing>
      <segmentKey>9W2732</segmentKey>
      <fareClass> W</fareClass>
    </FlightSegment>
    <FlightSegment>
      <segmentOutgoing>true</segmentOutgoing>
      <segmentKey>9W2376</segmentKey>
      <fareClass> Z</fareClass>
    </FlightSegment>
    <tripType>O</tripType>
    <ticketType>E</ticketType>
  </AirAvailabilityReply>
  <AirAvailabilityReply>
    <supplierType>S</supplierType>
    <RateInfo>
      <nativeBaseFare>271.0</nativeBaseFare>
      <nativeTotalPrice>393.0</nativeTotalPrice>
      <nativeCurrencyCode>USD</nativeCurrencyCode>
      <displayBaseFare>13414.5</displayBaseFare>
      <displayTotalPrice>19453.5</displayTotalPrice>
      <displayCurrencyCode>INR</displayCurrencyCode>
    </RateInfo>
    <FlightSegment>
      <segmentOutgoing>true</segmentOutgoing>
      <segmentKey>9W2370</segmentKey>
      <fareClass> O</fareClass>
    </FlightSegment>
    <FlightSegment>
      <segmentOutgoing>true</segmentOutgoing>
      <segmentKey>9W2312</segmentKey>
      <fareClass> Z</fareClass>
    </FlightSegment>
    <tripType>O</tripType>
    <ticketType>E</ticketType>
  </AirAvailabilityReply>
  <AirAvailabilityReply>
    <supplierType>S</supplierType>
    <RateInfo>
      <nativeBaseFare>290.0</nativeBaseFare>
      <nativeTotalPrice>402.9</nativeTotalPrice>
      <nativeCurrencyCode>USD</nativeCurrencyCode>
      <displayBaseFare>14355.0</displayBaseFare>
      <displayTotalPrice>19943.55</displayTotalPrice>
      <displayCurrencyCode>INR</displayCurrencyCode>
    </RateInfo>
    <FlightSegment>
      <segmentOutgoing>true</segmentOutgoing>
      <segmentKey>9W2329</segmentKey>
      <fareClass> Z</fareClass>
    </FlightSegment>
    <FlightSegment>
      <segmentOutgoing>true</segmentOutgoing>
      <segmentKey>S2234</segmentKey>
      <fareClass> G</fareClass>
    </FlightSegment>
    <tripType>O</tripType>
    <ticketType>E</ticketType>
  </AirAvailabilityReply>
  <AirAvailabilityReply>
    <supplierType>S</supplierType>
    <RateInfo>
      <nativeBaseFare>291.0</nativeBaseFare>
      <nativeTotalPrice>404.0</nativeTotalPrice>
      <nativeCurrencyCode>USD</nativeCurrencyCode>
      <displayBaseFare>14404.5</displayBaseFare>
      <displayTotalPrice>19998.0</displayTotalPrice>
      <displayCurrencyCode>INR</displayCurrencyCode>
    </RateInfo>
    <FlightSegment>
      <segmentOutgoing>true</segmentOutgoing>
      <segmentKey>9W2329</segmentKey>
      <fareClass> Z</fareClass>
    </FlightSegment>
    <FlightSegment>
      <segmentOutgoing>true</segmentOutgoing>
      <segmentKey>S23351</segmentKey>
      <fareClass> G</fareClass>
    </FlightSegment>
    <tripType>O</tripType>
    <ticketType>E</ticketType>
  </AirAvailabilityReply>
  <AirAvailabilityReply>
    <supplierType>S</supplierType>
    <RateInfo>
      <nativeBaseFare>290.0</nativeBaseFare>
      <nativeTotalPrice>406.3</nativeTotalPrice>
      <nativeCurrencyCode>USD</nativeCurrencyCode>
      <displayBaseFare>14355.0</displayBaseFare>
      <displayTotalPrice>20111.85</displayTotalPrice>
      <displayCurrencyCode>INR</displayCurrencyCode>
    </RateInfo>
    <FlightSegment>
      <segmentOutgoing>true</segmentOutgoing>
      <segmentKey>9W2329</segmentKey>
      <fareClass> Z</fareClass>
    </FlightSegment>
    <FlightSegment>
      <segmentOutgoing>true</segmentOutgoing>
      <segmentKey>9W7008</segmentKey>
      <fareClass> W</fareClass>
    </FlightSegment>
    <tripType>O</tripType>
    <ticketType>E</ticketType>
  </AirAvailabilityReply>
  <AirAvailabilityReply>
    <supplierType>S</supplierType>
    <RateInfo>
      <nativeBaseFare>339.0</nativeBaseFare>
      <nativeTotalPrice>456.9</nativeTotalPrice>
      <nativeCurrencyCode>USD</nativeCurrencyCode>
      <displayBaseFare>16780.5</displayBaseFare>
      <displayTotalPrice>22616.55</displayTotalPrice>
      <displayCurrencyCode>INR</displayCurrencyCode>
    </RateInfo>
    <FlightSegment>
      <segmentOutgoing>true</segmentOutgoing>
      <segmentKey>9W2730</segmentKey>
      <fareClass> N</fareClass>
    </FlightSegment>
    <FlightSegment>
      <segmentOutgoing>true</segmentOutgoing>
      <segmentKey>AI519</segmentKey>
      <fareClass> C</fareClass>
    </FlightSegment>
    <tripType>O</tripType>
    <ticketType>E</ticketType>
  </AirAvailabilityReply>
  <AirAvailabilityReply>
    <supplierType>S</supplierType>
    <RateInfo>
      <nativeBaseFare>462.99997</nativeBaseFare>
      <nativeTotalPrice>592.6</nativeTotalPrice>
      <nativeCurrencyCode>USD</nativeCurrencyCode>
      <displayBaseFare>22918.5</displayBaseFare>
      <displayTotalPrice>29333.7</displayTotalPrice>
      <displayCurrencyCode>INR</displayCurrencyCode>
    </RateInfo>
    <FlightSegment>
      <segmentOutgoing>true</segmentOutgoing>
      <segmentKey>AI519</segmentKey>
      <fareClass> C</fareClass>
    </FlightSegment>
    <FlightSegment>
      <segmentOutgoing>true</segmentOutgoing>
      <segmentKey>9W2713</segmentKey>
      <fareClass> N</fareClass>
    </FlightSegment>
    <tripType>O</tripType>
    <ticketType>E</ticketType>
  </AirAvailabilityReply>
  <AirAvailabilityReply>
    <supplierType>S</supplierType>
    <RateInfo>
      <nativeBaseFare>498.0</nativeBaseFare>
      <nativeTotalPrice>600.5</nativeTotalPrice>
      <nativeCurrencyCode>USD</nativeCurrencyCode>
      <displayBaseFare>24651.0</displayBaseFare>
      <displayTotalPrice>29724.75</displayTotalPrice>
      <displayCurrencyCode>INR</displayCurrencyCode>
    </RateInfo>
    <FlightSegment>
      <segmentOutgoing>true</segmentOutgoing>
      <segmentKey>UL166</segmentKey>
      <fareClass> J</fareClass>
    </FlightSegment>
    <FlightSegment>
      <segmentOutgoing>true</segmentOutgoing>
      <segmentKey>UL171</segmentKey>
      <fareClass> J</fareClass>
    </FlightSegment>
    <tripType>O</tripType>
    <ticketType>E</ticketType>
  </AirAvailabilityReply>
  <AirAvailabilityReply>
    <supplierType>S</supplierType>
    <RateInfo>
      <nativeBaseFare>498.0</nativeBaseFare>
      <nativeTotalPrice>600.5</nativeTotalPrice>
      <nativeCurrencyCode>USD</nativeCurrencyCode>
      <displayBaseFare>24651.0</displayBaseFare>
      <displayTotalPrice>29724.75</displayTotalPrice>
      <displayCurrencyCode>INR</displayCurrencyCode>
    </RateInfo>
    <FlightSegment>
      <segmentOutgoing>true</segmentOutgoing>
      <segmentKey>UL168</segmentKey>
      <fareClass> J</fareClass>
    </FlightSegment>
    <FlightSegment>
      <segmentOutgoing>true</segmentOutgoing>
      <segmentKey>UL171</segmentKey>
      <fareClass> J</fareClass>
    </FlightSegment>
    <tripType>O</tripType>
    <ticketType>E</ticketType>
  </AirAvailabilityReply>
  <AirAvailabilityReply>
    <supplierType>S</supplierType>
    <RateInfo>
      <nativeBaseFare>474.00003</nativeBaseFare>
      <nativeTotalPrice>612.4</nativeTotalPrice>
      <nativeCurrencyCode>USD</nativeCurrencyCode>
      <displayBaseFare>23463.0</displayBaseFare>
      <displayTotalPrice>30313.8</displayTotalPrice>
      <displayCurrencyCode>INR</displayCurrencyCode>
    </RateInfo>
    <FlightSegment>
      <segmentOutgoing>true</segmentOutgoing>
      <segmentKey>9W2370</segmentKey>
      <fareClass> N</fareClass>
    </FlightSegment>
    <FlightSegment>
      <segmentOutgoing>true</segmentOutgoing>
      <segmentKey>AI518</segmentKey>
      <fareClass> C</fareClass>
    </FlightSegment>
    <tripType>O</tripType>
    <ticketType>E</ticketType>
  </AirAvailabilityReply>
  <AirAvailabilityReply>
    <supplierType>S</supplierType>
    <RateInfo>
      <nativeBaseFare>528.0</nativeBaseFare>
      <nativeTotalPrice>664.3</nativeTotalPrice>
      <nativeCurrencyCode>USD</nativeCurrencyCode>
      <displayBaseFare>26136.0</displayBaseFare>
      <displayTotalPrice>32882.85</displayTotalPrice>
      <displayCurrencyCode>INR</displayCurrencyCode>
    </RateInfo>
    <FlightSegment>
      <segmentOutgoing>true</segmentOutgoing>
      <segmentKey>AI519</segmentKey>
      <fareClass> C</fareClass>
    </FlightSegment>
    <FlightSegment>
      <segmentOutgoing>true</segmentOutgoing>
      <segmentKey>9W2307</segmentKey>
      <fareClass> I</fareClass>
    </FlightSegment>
    <tripType>O</tripType>
    <ticketType>E</ticketType>
  </AirAvailabilityReply>
  <AirAvailabilityReply>
    <supplierType>S</supplierType>
    <RateInfo>
      <nativeBaseFare>599.0</nativeBaseFare>
      <nativeTotalPrice>717.6</nativeTotalPrice>
      <nativeCurrencyCode>USD</nativeCurrencyCode>
      <displayBaseFare>29650.5</displayBaseFare>
      <displayTotalPrice>35521.2</displayTotalPrice>
      <displayCurrencyCode>INR</displayCurrencyCode>
    </RateInfo>
    <FlightSegment>
      <segmentOutgoing>true</segmentOutgoing>
      <segmentKey>UL166</segmentKey>
      <fareClass> J</fareClass>
    </FlightSegment>
    <FlightSegment>
      <segmentOutgoing>true</segmentOutgoing>
      <segmentKey>UL127</segmentKey>
      <fareClass> C</fareClass>
    </FlightSegment>
    <FlightSegment>
      <segmentOutgoing>true</segmentOutgoing>
      <segmentKey>9W2713</segmentKey>
      <fareClass> N</fareClass>
    </FlightSegment>
    <tripType>O</tripType>
    <ticketType>E</ticketType>
  </AirAvailabilityReply>
  <cacheKey>1206cebb:135d71daacc:-6a55</cacheKey>
  <cacheLocation>10.186.168.42:7302</cacheLocation>
</AirAvailabilityResults>
```

PLEASE NOTE I HAVE DELETED THE SEGMENT LIST FROM HERE

PLEASE REPLAY. Or ANY OTHER GOOD API TO IMPLEMENT air SEARCH AND BOOKING

PLEASE  HELP ME. I AM IN A SERIOS PROBLEM WITH THIS ISSUE

Comment: It throws me this error  -1  1  4  TravelNow.com cannot service this request.  Authentication failure. (cid=-1; ipAddress= 122.322.33.000)

Comment: it is easy to parse from there site  tell me data path of the site ,,i mean the page you are requesting for